# Classifying singularities of $\frac {z^{1/2}-1}{\sin{\pi z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, branch-cuts, branch-points

I am trying to classify the singularities of $$\frac {z^{1/2}-1}{\sin{\pi z}}$$
where $-\pi<\arg z<\pi$.

I am confused by this because of the branch cut of $\sqrt z$ but here is my (bad) attempt:

The singularities are at $z = n$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$. We have a branch point at $z=0$ so this is a non-isolated singularity (not a simple pole, as I almost said). When $z$ is a negative integer the function is not even defined so I suppose these are not considered singularities? For $n=1$ it is removable since $1$ is a simple zero of both the numerator and denominator - the derivative of $z^{1/2}-1$ is $z^{-1/2}/2$ which is non-zero at $z=1$ so it must be a simple zero. Is that right? Then for $n>1$ we just have simple poles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the square root see [What are the branches of square root function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2536235)

So let us consider the function $z^{1/2}$. Although $0^{1/2}$ is of course well-defined, we must exclude $z = 0$ because we want to obtain a holomorphic function (these are defined only on open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$).

This means that the (holomorphic) function

$$f(z) = \frac{z^{1/2}-1}{\sin\pi z}$$

is defined on $U = \mathbb{C} \backslash ((-\infty,0] \cup \lbrace 1,2, 3, ... \rbrace)$. The singularities are at the points $n = 1,2,3,...$. All your arguments concerning these points are correct.

Comment: Last sentence: I think you want to say "isolated singularities"

Comment: @zhw Yes, of course! This is implicit in my answer since $\lbrace 1,2,3,... \rbrace$ does not have a cluster point.